# Line segment, sum of supplementary angles to internal ones.

Tags: geometry

Having hard time understanding this drawing. Essentially the questions about finding the sum of the supplementary angles to the internal angles of a non standard polygon. I have the answer as roughly 720 degrees by measurement but my only clue to how is the fact that there are essentially 2 revolutions meaning the sum of exterior would be twice that of a single standard polygon (360 degrees).

[image: http://s21.postimg.org/9s7d0srbr/image.jpg]

Cheers,
J

Answer (score 1):

Consider each of the vertices of the polygon. Let us assume that the little angle you have drawn there is an arc of a unit circle centered at that vertex. Then the angle in radians equals the length of that curve. Now consider any two neighboring vertices. You can see that if you move one of the arcs to the circle centered at one of the vertices, that the two arcs join together into one longer arc, whose length is the sum of the two angles. Now start at one vertex $x$ and traverse the polygon from vertex to vertex, moving the drawn arc there to the circle centered at $x$. When you've joined together all the arcs you end up with a curve which moves around the full circle exactly twice. The length of this curve is twice the circumference of the circle, $2\cdot2\pi$, which corresponds to the angle $2\cdot 360^\circ=720^\circ$.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense now. Would rate if I could.